# Reading "length-delimited" files in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, dataframe

Consider the following file, `test.dat`:

```
123ABC3.5401
456DEF3.9001
789FED10.902
122GRE16.003
133SSA42.102
145ASS45.001
```

This is technically a columnar file, although that fact is not perhaps as clear as it would be were the file a CSV.

The columns for this file are delimited as such: `ID` is the first three characters (that is, runs from index 0 to 2, inclusive for a zero-indexed string), `Group` runs from the fourth through sixth characters, and `Value` takes up characters seven through twelve.

Here's how I'm currently reading this file in and converting it to a `pandas.DataFrame` object:

```
import pandas as pd

col_lengths = {'ID': range(0, 3), 'Group': range(3, 6), 'Value': range(6, 12)}
col_lengths = {k: set(v) for k, v in col_lengths.items()}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=col_lengths.keys())

with open('length_delimiter_test.dat', 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        current = row.strip()
        values_enum = list(enumerate(current))
        row_dict = {col: ''.join(v for idx, v in values_enum if idx in col_lengths[col]) for col in col_lengths}
        df = df.append(row_dict, ignore_index=True)
```

Which gives me what I want:

```
  Group   ID   Value
0   ABC  123  3.5401
1   DEF  456  3.9001
2   FED  789  10.902
3   GRE  122  16.003
4   SSA  133  42.102
5   ASS  145  45.001
```

This approach is a bit verbose for my taste, however. I would like basically to pass my `col_lengths` dictionary above to a `pandas.read_table`-like function, but I didn't see anything in the pandas documentation that would allow such behavior. Something like this:

```
df = pd.read_table('length_delimiter_test.dat', col_parser=col_lengths)
```

Does anyone know of more concise, built-in functionality in pandas (or any Python package, for that matter)? I didn't find any robust package around parsing length-delimited files like this.

Edit: Thanks to [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741205/maxu) for referring me to [`pandas.read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
pd.read_fwf('length_delimiter_test.dat', colspecs=[(min(x), max(x)+1) for x in col_lengths.values()], header=None, names=col_lengths.keys())
Out[55]: 
 Group   ID    Value
0  ABC  123   3.5401
1  DEF  456   3.9001
2  FED  789  10.9020
3  GRE  122  16.0030
4  SSA  133  42.1020
5  ASS  145  45.0010
```

Comment: did you try `pd.read_fwf(...)`?

Comment: @MaxU I must've completely missed that. That's exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: For your particular use-case `pd.read_fwf(f, widths=[3, 3, 6], names=['Group', 'ID', 'Value'])`

Comment: you can also add `names=col_lengths.keys()`

Comment: Found that as I read deeper in the docs. Thanks.

Comment: So, please post the answer as an answer, not as an edit on the question.  Otherwise, some of us come by later to see if a question needs an answer and we read all of this only to find that the question has been answered, but not answered....  If you know what I mean.  And since you have LOTS of rep, you do know what I mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741205/maxu) (he should really get the credit for this answer) for referring me to [`pandas.read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
pd.read_fwf('length_delimiter_test.dat', colspecs=[(min(x), max(x)+1) for x in col_lengths.values()], header=None, names=col_lengths.keys())
Out[55]: 
 Group   ID    Value
0  ABC  123   3.5401
1  DEF  456   3.9001
2  FED  789  10.9020
3  GRE  122  16.0030
4  SSA  133  42.1020
5  ASS  145  45.0010
```